# Rails 4, delayed_job, rspec: setting an attribute to Delayed::Job.last.id...how to test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, delayed-job

I enqueue a mailer for future delivery when a user clicks a button. If the user cancels the original action, I want to un-queue the to-be-delivered mailer

To do so, I store the ActiveJob id as an attribute on the enqueued job's payload object (the alternative is parsing YAML stuff along the lines of [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/306) to locate the payload object).

This line does the work (located in the payload object's model file)

```
self.update_attributes enqueued_job_id: Delayed::Job.last.id
```

In my model specs, since mailers are not actually enqueued, Rspec keeps thinking Delayed::Job is nil, so all of the payload model's specs fail.

Question: If (a big 'if') my approach to this problem is 'correct,' how can I make get my model specs to pass?